# Clojure: documentation

Tags: clojure

I am working through this tutorial: http://moxleystratton.com/clojure/clojure-tutorial-for-the-non-lisp-programmer

And came across this snippet:

```
user=> (loop [i 0]
  (when (< i 5)
    (println "i:" i)
    (recur (inc i))))
i: 0
i: 1
i: 2
i: 3
i: 4
nil
```

Works great on my interpreter!

```
❯ lein repl
nREPL server started on port 50974
REPL-y 0.1.10
Clojure 1.5.1
```

Now I am looking for some documentation on what `recur` is.

It's not in here!
http://clojure.github.io/clojure/api-index.html

It took me a while to figure out it's a "Special Form" and thus described in [this page](http://clojure.org/special_forms).

Is there a compilation out there that has a single coherent index?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using the built in documentation in the REPL:

```
user=> (doc recur)
-------------------------
recur
  (recur exprs*)
Special Form
  Evaluates the exprs in order, then, in parallel, rebinds
  the bindings of the recursion point to the values of the exprs.
  Execution then jumps back to the recursion point, a loop or fn method.

  Please see http://clojure.org/special_forms#recur
```

It works on functions, macros, special forms, variables—almost everything.

Comment: (use 'clojure.repl) to use this in namespaces other than 'user

Answer (score 2):

The search box on clojuredocs.org is a great starting place to start and they offer a very [complete list](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core) of forms and functions. Be aware that at present Clojure Docs is not up to date with the latest version of clojure though so there are some minor differences. In practice the [official api page](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/) is complete enough and the most up to date. It does not have all the special forms, though there are very few special forms in clojure so this is not often a problem

Comment: I have been making use of clojuredocs.org as well. But for example nothing is found for `for` on the search there. I guess there will be an entry in at least one of these two sites for any particular form/func/var.

Comment: clojuredocs search is a bit strange. 'for' returns no result for for, but if you type for in the search box and wait a second, you'll see the entry for for. Or, you can go directly to the resource, with http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/for -- subsituting terms as necessary.